# number of leaves in a strict binary tree

Tags: algorithm

I looking for derivation how we came to following result.

sum of 2 to power of i, as i goes from 0 to n => answer is given as (2 power of (n+1) -1).

Can any one show me how we achieved above result or to proper link where we have solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Proof by induction: for n=0, 2^0 = 1 = 2^1 - 1. Assuming that it's true for n=k-1, 2^0 + ... + 2^k = 2^0 + ... + 2^(k-1) + 2^k = (2^k - 1) + 2^k = 2*2^k - 1 = 2^(k+1) - 1 as required.

Comment: actually that's the number of nodes, not leaves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof by induction.

Observe it's true for n=0 - sum0->0 = 1 = 2^1 - 1

Assume true for n = k-1, so sum[0->k-1] = 2^k - 1.
Then sum[0->k] = sum[0->k-1] + 2^k = 2^k - 1 + 2^k = 2(2^k) - 1 = 2^(k+1) - 1.

Therefore true for all n.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the mathematical [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression).

If you want a clearer (more intuitive) explanation, you can read [this nice explanation](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-geometric.html)